# Make API query to only one Stack Exchange site

Tags: support, documentation

Is there a way to limit a /search or a /similar query to a specific site or sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition all `/search` and `/similar` queries are made on one specific site. There is currently no way to search more than one site.

**Example:**

> http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?intitle=linq

This example will search *only* Stack Overflow for the term `linq`.

Comment: ah, thanks! so there's no api to search across all SE sites?

Comment: @swasheck: Nope. Not currently.